# How to reduce columns from three to two without it moving below - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I am trying to use this piece of html/css http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/grid-columns-divider for a line divider. However; when I try to get rid of one column and have it just as 2 column with a 25%/75% split it glitches out and makes it go below it and the line divider disappears. Also, how would I get the line divider to not be as near the top as it currently is, I want there to be a gap at the top.

```css
/* Tablet and bigger */
@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
    .grid-divider {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .grid-divider>[class*='col-'] {
        position: static;
    }
    .grid-divider>[class*='col-']:nth-child(n+2):before {
        content: "";
        border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .col-padding {
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Add the (.grid-divider) class to any row to separate grid columns with equal height lines.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row grid-divider">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-padding">
        <h3>Column 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima expedita incidunt rerum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-padding">
        <h3>Column 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate placeat suscipit maxime tenetur officiis asperiores quae molestias fugiat praesentium dolorum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-padding">
        <h3>Column 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab veniam aperiam numquam cupiditate maiores repudiandae ea dicta, sunt rerum corporis. Ab veniam aperiam numquam cupiditate maiores repudiandae ea dicta, sunt rerum corporis. Ab veniam aperiam numquam cupiditate maiores repudiandae ea dicta.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the modified `snippet` below.

I have added a class `.pb-15` to give a gap to the top divider as you requested.

```css
/* Tablet and bigger */
@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
    .grid-divider {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .grid-divider>[class*='col-'] {
        position: static;
    }
    .grid-divider>[class*='col-']:nth-child(n+2):before {
        content: "";
        border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .col-padding {
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
}

.pb-15 {
  padding-bottom: 15px!important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header pb-15">
        <h3>Add the (.grid-divider) class to any row to separate grid columns with equal height lines.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row grid-divider">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="col-padding">
        <h3>Column 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima expedita incidunt rerum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="col-padding">
        <h3>Column 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate placeat suscipit maxime tenetur officiis asperiores quae molestias fugiat praesentium dolorum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to restrict the text from going past my other columns because at the moment it is going more than 100%.

Comment: can you place a screenshot please as I can't see the same in my above sample?